# How to get top generated text of T5 transformers?

Tags: simpletransformers

I trained a T5 transformer using `simpletransformers` library.

Here is a code to get the predictions:

```
pred_values = model.predict(input_values)
```

However, it just returns the top or greedy prediction, how can I get 10 top results?

Comment: If you are using hugging-face transformers, then you can try using `generate()`:
`output_sequences = model.generate(input_ids=input_values, max_length=<MAX_LEN_TOKENS>, num_beams=10, num_return_sequences=10)`

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa thank you, simpletransformers also have such settings and I sent it as answer.

Answer (score 6):

The required parameter is `num_return_sequences`, which shows the number of samples to generate. However, you should also set a number for beam search if you want to use a beam search algorithm.

```
model_args = T5Args()
model_args.num_beams = 5
model_args.num_return_sequences = 2
```

Alternatively, you can use `top_k` or `top_p` to generate and select among top samples, in these cases, you must set `do_sample` to `True`. For more information about the parameters refer to [1] and [2], which is a detailed explanation.

```
model_args = T5Args()
model_args.do_sample = True
model_args.top_p = 0.9
model_args.num_return_sequences = 2
```

[1] https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/t5-model/

[2] https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate